# Script to parse a large text file, from rows to columns

Tags: parsing

I want a parsing script/ code solution in any programing language.

The file is too large to be open in Excel.

Problem:

I have large text file (300MB) which look like this:

```
[0] 2014 Jul 23  08:15:16.675  

   Current SFN               = 604
   Current Subframe Number   = 3
   Is Restricted             = false
   Cell Timing[0]            = 298955

[1]  2014 Jul 24  08:15:16.675  

   Current SFN               = 605
   Current Subframe Number   = 4
   Is Restricted             = false
   Cell Timing[0]            = 298900

[2] 2014 Jul 25  08:15:16.675  

   Current SFN               = 700
   Current Subframe Number   = 7
   Is Restricted             = false
   Cell Timing[0]            = 39025
```

Wanted output:

5 columns (  Date , Current SFN , Current Subframe Number   ,   Is Restricted  , Cell Timing[0] )

```
Date     Current SFN     Current Subframe Number       Is Restricted     Cell Timing[0]
2014 Jul 23  08:15:16.675   604 3   TRUE    298955
2014 Jul 24  08:15:16.675   605 4   FALSE   298900
2014 Jul 25  08:15:16.675   700 7   FALSE   39025
```

Comment: Solution: learn programming.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not a site to ask for code, but instead to ask for help about coding.

Comment: This is not how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: (1) Split the file in smaller ones (you can use copy-pasting), (2) open the small files in Excel to apply the formatting, (3) concatenate the results (you can use copy-pasting)